# how to pattern substitue the result from a shell command piped to another shell command

Tags: shell, csh

I have a lot of files which have a odd naming. For instance, `file_1_0_a32.elf
, file_2_1_a32.elf, file_3_2_a32.elf` in a directory. I want to rename the files to new name removing the `_1_a32` in file `file_2_1_a32.elf` so name becomes `file_2.elf`. I can easily write a file with list of files and new names with mv and execute the file. I was wondering if i can do this via command line itself. I was hoping `xargs` command can be useful here. This is all that i could come up with `ls *.elf | xargs -i mv {} modifiedFileName`. I don't know how to complete this. Basically i want to have another stage to correct the file names returned by `ls` and also keep the original name so i can use it as argument for `mv`. Is there a way i could do it?

Answer (score 1):

There exists a tool for this use case: `rename`

```
rename 's/_\d_a32//' *.elf
```

The `xargs` use case is to use the piped value as is. If you want to modify the piped value AND have the original value then `xargs` is not the right tool for the job. In such a case it is better to use a `while read` loop in combination with search and replace in bash parameter expansion.

```
ls *.elf | while read -r filename
do
  mv "$filename" "${filename/_?_a32}"
done
```

For more information about search and replace in bash parameter expansion: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace

Beware that this will overwrite without asking: `file_1_0_a32.elf` and `file_1_1_a32.elf` will both be renamed to `file_1.elf` with one overwritten. It only replaces the pattern if the number between underscores is single digit (replaced: `_3_a32`, not replaced: `_13_a32`). It also replaces the pattern if any single character is between the underscores (replaced: `_x_a32`). Unfortunately there is no easy way to work around this limitation without using another tool altogether (hint: `rename` is a good tool for this use case).

The `rename` tool is sometimes called prename (perl rename) and is often installed as part of the perl package. Here is the manpage in ubuntu: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/prename.1.html

Comment: Obligatory warning: there's two tools by the name of `rename` and only one of them supports this syntax.

Comment: @lesmana Thanks for the info about rename tool. I was not aware of it. But i have difficulty in making it to work, my requirement is still to rename files but files are differently named i want to rename `file_5_6.s`  to `file_5_a32.s` i tried variation of this `rename -v 's/_\d+\.s$/_a32\.s/' *.s ` but it dose not work, it makes no changes to file. Something wrong with regular expression i am using. what could be wrong with this?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz how do i find out which is the rename tool that i have i checked the man page for rename in my computer, it dose not mention regular expression, dose it mean that the syntax mentioned will not work?